# Configuring snmp on ESXi server using VI Java api

Tags: java, snmp, esxi

I am trying to configure snmp on ESX-i server. 
For this i am using VI Java api. For this i am using recent vi jars. 
This is the code.

```
import java.net.URL;

import com.vmware.vim25.HostSnmpConfigSpec;
import com.vmware.vim25.HostSnmpDestination;
import com.vmware.vim25.mo.Folder;
import com.vmware.vim25.mo.HostSnmpSystem;
import com.vmware.vim25.mo.HostSystem;
import com.vmware.vim25.mo.InventoryNavigator;
import com.vmware.vim25.mo.ServiceInstance;

public class ConfigureSnmpSystem
{

    private static final String URL_VCENTER = "https://10.118.67.36/sdk";
    private static final String username = "Admin";
    private static final String password = "passwd";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ServiceInstance si = new ServiceInstance(new URL(URL_VCENTER), username,
            password, true);

    String hostname = "10.108.30.12"; // this is the ip address of esx-i server
    Folder rootFolder = si.getRootFolder();
    HostSystem host = null;
    host = (HostSystem) new InventoryNavigator(rootFolder)
            .searchManagedEntity("HostSystem", hostname);

    if (host == null) {
        System.out.println("Cannot find the host:" + hostname);
        si.getServerConnection().logout();
        return;
    }

    HostSnmpSystem hss = host.getHostSnmpSystem();

    HostSnmpConfigSpec spec = new HostSnmpConfigSpec();
    spec.setEnabled(true);
    spec.setReadOnlyCommunities(new String[] { "visdk" });
    HostSnmpDestination dest = new HostSnmpDestination();
    dest.setCommunity("visdk");
    dest.setHostName("10.108.67.46");
    dest.setPort(162);
    spec.setTrapTargets(new HostSnmpDestination[] { dest });

    hss.reconfigureSnmpAgent(spec);
    si.getServerConnection().logout();
}
}
```

The error comes `HostSnmpSystem hss = host.getHostSnmpSystem();`
hss comes out to be null

unable to guess the error.

Answer (score 0):

vCenter Server doesn't yet support configuring per ESX (hostSystem) snmp.
I think that should finally be available in 5.5 IIRC.

Also note that since ESX 5.1 there is now support for SNMPv3, though its configured
using 'esxcli system snmp set|get' cmds, VIM API only supports SNMPv1.